# Move all default values into one python file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have one python file containing all default values for every other classes in my project

```
# config.py
DEFAULT_WORKER_TYPE = 'A'
DEFAULT_METRIC_TYPE = 'euclid'
...

# worker.py
import config
class Worker:
    def __init__(self, worker_type=config.DEFAULT_WORKER_TYPE):
        pass

# metric.py
import config
class Metric:
    def __init__(self, metric_type=config.DEFAULT_METRIC_TYPE):
        pass
```

This works fine but then I want to use `Enum` for `worker_type` and `metric_type` instead of raw strings to avoid typo

```
# config.py
from worker import WorkerType
from metric import MetricType

DEFAULT_WORKER_TYPE = WorkerType.A
DEFAULT_METRIC_TYPE = MetricType.EUCLID

# worker.py
from enum import Enum
import config

class WorkerType(Enum):
    A = 'A'
    B = 'B'

class Worker: # the same

# metric.py
from enum import Enum
import config

class MetricType(Enum):
    EUCLID = 'euclid'
    MANHATTAN = 'manhattan'

class Metric: # the same
```

Now, it appears to me that the latter version is not very efficient because it has some kind of circular import, and if my main program use only one file (`worker.py` for example), it still has to import every other file (`metric.py`) because `config.py` import all of them.

Is there any better way to achieve this?

The reason I move all default values into `config.py` is that I need to do experiments quite regularly with these values. Putting everything in one place help me not have to remember which file to change.

Comment: Is there a reason you couldn't put all enum classes and values into a separate python file?  Such as `my_enums.py`?

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you can use the classical approach which consists in putting each class in a single module.

In `worker_type.py`:

```
import enum

class WorkerType(enum.Enum):
    A = 'A'
    B = 'B'
```

In `metric_type.py`:

```
import enum

class MetricType(enum.Enum):
    EUCLID = 'euclid'
    MANHATTAN = 'manhattan'
```

Then you can define your configuration file like this:

```
import worker_type
import metric_type

DEFAULT_WORKER_TYPE = worker_type.WorkerType.A
DEFAULT_METRIC_TYPE = metric_type.MetricType.EUCLID
```

That way, your `worker.py` stay unchanged:

```
import config

class Worker:
    def __init__(self, worker_type=config.DEFAULT_WORKER_TYPE):
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Those enums should be in your config file or at least the values. You're not using your config.py file as a config file if you program it that way. Do something like below but code it properly.

```
# config.py
from enum import Enum

class WorkerType(Enum):
    A = 'A'
    B = 'B'

class MetricType(Enum):
    EUCLID = 'euclid'
    MANHATTAN = 'manhattan'

DEFAULT_WORKER_TYPE = WorkerType.A
DEFAULT_METRIC_TYPE = MetricType.EUCLID

# worker.py
import config

class Worker: # the same

# metric.py
import config

class Metric: # the same
```

And import only what you need from config. It's less to type and easier to read in my mind.